# Apache POI getRow() returns null when num of rows more then 50

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, apache-poi

I try to autosize columns, but when the number of rows is more then 50 sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() suddenly returns null.

If num of rows less then 50 it works fine.

```
 private void setColumnSize(SXSSFSheet sheet) {
        sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
        short lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        for (int i = 0; i < lastCellNum; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
    }
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> ru.fabit.visor.core.servercomplexesmanagement.report.service.impl.CameraReportExcelConverterImpl.setColumnSize(CameraReportExcelConverterImpl.java:92)

maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```